# Informatica Data Quality - Match Analysis

Tags: informatica-powercenter, data-quality

In our Duplicate analysis requirement the input data has 1418 records out of which 1380 records are duplicate records.

On using the Match Analysis (used Key Generator, Matcher, Associator, Consolidator) in IDQ integrated with PowerCenter except for 8 records all duplicates were eliminated.

On executing the workflow by excluding these records, duplicates appear in other records for which duplicate didnt occur in the previous run.

Can anyone tell why this mismatch occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Consolidator transformation is not getting correct association ids and hence inserting multiple records resulting in duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

please try the below steps:

1) Try to create a workflow in IDQ itself by deploying the mapping which you developed in IDQ.

2) Also keep a check on the business keys of the records which make a primary key through which you are identifying the dups in source.